# Why did hasExited throw 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'?

Tags: c#, process

I can successfully run a new process using ShellExecuteEx, but if I access the HasExited property, a Win32Exception is thrown.  What is this exception and how do I check if the process is alive?

```
ShellExecuteEx(ref info);
clientProcessId = NativeMethods.GetProcessId(info.hProcess);
Process clientProcess = Process.GetProcessById((int)clientProcessId);

if (clientProcess.HasExited) //<---- throws Win32Exception, but the process is alive! I can see its window
{
   //run new one
}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you getting the exception on Vista or Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, did you set fMask to `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`, so that hProcess is valid?

Also, why are you P/Invoke'ing to ShellExecuteEx, why not use Process.Start w/ ProcessStartInfo, which will handle ShellExecuteEx for you?

EDIT: Since you are doing runas, you only get SYNCHRONIZE access on the handle, not `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access, hence GetExitCodeProcess fails, which results in hasEnded throwing a Win32 exception.

As a workaround, you could P/Invoke WaitForSingleObject with a timeout of zero to see if the process has exited.

Comment: sure I set the fMask else I would not be able to get the handle of the process. I use this function to be able to run the process as elevated in Vista as "runas". As I know it's the one opportunity to do so in Vista.

Comment: Thanks, the runas explains why you're seeing this.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today. There is another solution. The WaitForExit function runs fine on another user environment.
So if you do a runas to elevate the process privileges, you can query the process status with this function.

Answer (score -1):

likely throws an error because the object doesnt exist anymore and therefore your checking a object that is destroyed

similar issue arises in vb when dealing with pictures

```
function openimg(imgpath)
img = get image from path
return img
end function
```

that will not return an image properly for some reason

instead the line needs to be

return img.clone() to properly return the image

however thats my example